# Bindings in Ruby. What is a good way to think of them. What do they contain

Tags: ruby, binding

I am confused about bindings.

```
def repl(input_stream, output_stream)
  loop do
    output_stream.print "> "
    input  = input_stream.gets()
    result = binding.eval(input)
    output_stream.puts(result)
  end
end

repl($stdin, $stdout)
```

I am going to call repl with just $stdin and $stdout. I need a dumbed down version of what the line:

```
binding.eval(input) is doing.
```

Bindings are just where we currently are in the call stack right? They hold the current local variables? Anything else? What's a good way to think of them differently from the current scope?

Answer (score 0):

Objects of class Binding encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use. The variables, methods, value of self, and possibly an iterator block that can be accessed in this context are all retained. Binding objects can be created using Kernel#binding, and are made available to the callback of Kernel#set_trace_func.

```
               static VALUE
bind_local_variable_defined_p(VALUE bindval, VALUE sym)
{
    ID lid = check_local_id(bindval, &sym);
    const rb_binding_t *bind;

    if (!lid) return Qfalse;

    GetBindingPtr(bindval, bind);
    return get_local_variable_ptr(bind->env, lid) ? Qtrue : Qfalse;
}
```

Here is a example of Public Instance Methods

```
def get_binding(param)
  return binding
end
b = get_binding("hello")
b.eval("param")   #=> "hello"
```